Emptying a certain graph by removing substructures
First recall the definition of a claw graph which is a tree with one node we call the parent connected to three nodes we call the children that have no other connections. The graphs we will consider in this problem are graphs formed by adjoining claw graphs with the following rules. Before I say the rules, I define attaching by meaning identifying one node with the node of another graph. Now for the rules:

We can not attach the parent of a claw to any other parent of another claw.

For any claw $C$ in the graph $G$, any child in $C$ can only be attached to exactly one other child of a different claw.

For any cycle (a closed walk in which all nodes are distinct) in the graph $G$, we can not have an edge not a part of the cycle inside the cycle.


Now, the aim of this problem is to reduce the graph to the empty set via the following two operations.
First, we can apply the operation $A$ to remove any claw in a graph if it has two nodes of degree 1.
Second, we can apply the operation $B$ to remove a claw from a cycle if there exists one in $G$.
Can we show that any graph $G$ satisfying the mentioned rules can be reduced to the empty set by applying $A$ and $B$?

When you say "We cannot have an edge not a part of the cycle inside the cycle", what does that mean? Are you think of these as planar graphs with a fixed plane embedding, so that "inside" means "geometrically inside"? Or are you saying that cycles should not have chords?

Second question: does operation A also apply to claws with three degree 1 nodes? If not, there's an easy counterexample: attach the parents of three claws to the three children of a fourth claw.

Hi, thanks for the interest. I wasn't sure exactly how to phrase rule 3. But looking at this image, I don't allow things like edges connected to a degree 1 node geometrically inside of a cycle, but I do allow edges inside of a cycle if they're not connected to a node of degree 1.
Also, yes I meant two or three degree 1 nodes for the definition of $A$.

I guess, in the end, that condition didn't end up mattering.

@MishaLavrov Yeah, maybe for some context, this is actually a question about triangulations. Essentially, each claw in the graph represents a triangle in a triangulation. A 1 degree node corresponds to a boundary edge, while a two degree node corresponds to an interior edge. The problem I was actually trying to solve involved removing all triangles from a triangulation of a contractible domain. The third condition represented the fact that a hole in your triangulated domain would mean there was a triangle with a boundary edge inside and I was not allowing that.

And so your lemma is saying that a triangulation of a contractible domain will either contain a triangle with two boundary edges or contain an interior vertex. This is basically the statement I was looking for and the equivalence between containing a cycle and existence of an interior vertex comes from contractibility. So in translating my problem to the graph setting, I did not need to include this third condition as the problem on graphs applies more generally.

The important thing to do is to prove the following lemma:
Lemma. Every graph $G$ built from claws in this way either

Contains a claw with two vertices of degree $1$, or
Contains a cycle.

From this lemma, it follows that we can always apply either operation A or operation B, and then repeat on the remaining graph until nothing is left.

To prove the lemma, assume that every claw contains at most one vertex of degree $1$. Starting at the parent of an arbitrary claw, repeat the following:

Walk in the current claw to the nearest vertex it shares with another claw other than the current vertex. (There must be at least $2$ such vertices, because otherwise the current claw would have $2$ degree-$1$ vertices.)
Make that other claw the new "current claw".

Repeat this process until we revisit a claw we've already seen before - and, if necessary, walk to a vertex of that claw we've already seen. This is a closed walk, and it does not use any edge twice, so it must contain a cycle.
